# How to use Google transliterate API in Angular 4/5?

Tags: angular, internationalization, transliteration, tamil

> How to use the [Google Transliterate API](https://developers.google.com/transliterate/) in angular 4/5 ? Kindly check the below mentioned code.

```
google.load("elements", "1", {
      packages: "transliteration"
});
function onLoad() {
  var options = {
      sourceLanguage:
          google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.ENGLISH,
      destinationLanguage:
          [google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.TAMIL],
      shortcutKey: 'ctrl+g',
      transliterationEnabled: true
  };
  var control =
      new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('getCountry');
  control.makeTransliteratable(elements);
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(onLoad);
```

Currently, I am using those code in the index.html page, but I want to import as the module in angular 4/5 in each component.

Comment: It's better to leave the question in English. Your question in tamil is also wrong. You asked "How to use Google API to write in tamil" this in tamil. So change your Question text.

Comment: Please edit the title of your question to be in English as well. StackOverflow requires questions (and question titles) to be in English or your question will be flagged and closed.

Comment: Yes, now I have changed to English.